# how can we relate two custom fields like if i select some value in one , it automatically shown in other in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

how can we relate two custom fields like if i select some value in one , it automatically shown in other in wordpress?
Let Suppose , i create two custom content type like Recipes and Shows. now i create two custom fields(type relation) respectively , one under Recipes named related_shows and other in Shows named related_recipes. Now i select one (Shows post) from related_shows field in Recipes. What i want , when i go to Shows post it automatically display that recipe in related_recipes field as added by own.Because that Shows we already assigned in Recipes(related_recipes). How can we do that? Many to many relation like if we select related_shows in Recipes, it automatically display that Recipes in Shows(related_recipes), we do not need to add it there .

Comment: What did you try actually ? How do you handle your custom fields (plugin) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we relate and show details automatically in custom fields relation of two custom types in wordpress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422043/how-can-we-relate-and-show-details-automatically-in-custom-fields-relation-of-tw)

Answer (score 0):

If your "custom content types" are WordPress custom post types, you can relate them using the [Posts 2 Posts plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/).  It should do what you need.